# How to get query from url and send it to Store at nuxt js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project I let users to download Pdf, when users clicked the link I will direct users to a new page .In here,I want to take url queries(informations) in this page and send it to store to return state informations . When I get state information i will show it in current page .

```
http://localhost:3000/printPdf?pdfId=690a9567-4c36-41c0-893c-587be307df25&number=1153379003428
```

This is my link. When user clicked it , I will take printId and number in store and i will return a state to create my pdf.
I used created and Asyncdata also .

```
  asyncData({app, params, route, store}) {
        const url = route.query

        store.dispatch('POST_PDF_PRINT', url)
          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asyncData we can do

```
   asyncData({app, params, route, store}) {
               
                    //through route
                    console.log(route.params.url)
                    //through param
                    console.log(params.url)
          
            }
```

In the mounted method, we can access param through $route object.

```
 mounted() {
       //for full path
       this.$route.fullPath
       //for route param
       this.$route.params.url
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`{{ $route.query.your_key }}`